# Illegal Break Statement NodeJs & Cheerio

Tags: node.js, loops, puppeteer, cheerio

I'm trying to loop the the .map function until the condition is met. I want to break the loop once the condition is met but i get the illegal break statement output. Im fairly new to node js and cheerio.

```
async function checkproduct() {
    const browser = await puppeteer.launch({headless: false});
       const page = await browser.newPage();
       const page2 = await browser.newPage();

const maxRetryNumber = Infinity; 
let success = false;
await page.goto("https://www.example.com");

for (let retryNumber = 1; retryNumber <= maxRetryNumber; retryNumber++) {
   
  await page.reload();
     const html = await page.content()
        const $ = cheerio.load(html);
       
        const results = $(".c-products__item").map((index,element) => {    
           
        const titleElement = $(element).find(".node--view-mode-search-result");
            
        const title = $(titleElement).attr("gtm-name");
        
   if( title == "abc" ){ 
        
         const urlElement = $(element).find(".product-selected-url");
            
         const url = $(urlElement).attr("href");
         const skuShoe = $(titleElement).attr("data-sku");
     
         console.log(url)
         success = true;
         break;
         return{title,url,skuShoe}
        }   
      
      }).get();
    
      return results;
    }
}


checkproduct();
```

Comment: Please put some effort into formatting your code to make it easier to read.  That will make it easier for people to help you.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to `break` a `.map()` loop.  Your `break` is inside a regular function and not directly in a `for` loop, therefore it's not a legal statement where it is.

If all you really want to do is `return` from your outer function when some condition is met, then change the `.map()` to a `for` loop and you can then return from the outer function when the condition is met.  FYI, there is need to use `break` right before a return.  You can just `return` from a function anywhere.  But, when you're inside a `.map()` callback, you can't return from the outer function, you can only return from the `.map()` callback.

If what you want to do is to break from the `.map()` loop, then convert the `.map()` loop to a `for` loop and you can then `break` from it.

There is no way to break from an outer `for` loop from inside an inner loop.  You either reorganize the code or use some flags you can check to break out of the inner loop and then hck the flag in the outer loop to then break out of the inner loop.